# index.blade.php file not returning any view or scripts?

Tags: php, laravel, model-view-controller, laravel-5.5

I'm facing an issue regarding my recent project, where i was trying to save some date through a form in the database (which is working as expected) but when i tried to fetch that data from my database it is not showing me any thing (as if code is not even there) in the view not even scripts but the same code is working in an other view.
[image: code which is supposed to be executed]
[image: returned view]

Controller code:

```
 public function index()
    {
        $products = Product::all();
        return view('product.index',compact('products'));

    }
```

Blade code:

```
@include('includes.header')
<div id="page-wrapper">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12" style="margin: 30px" >
            <table class="table table-bordered col-md-12 table-sm">
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>ID</th>
                    <th>Image</th>
                    <th>Company Name</th>
                    <th>Title</th>
                    <th>Price</th>
                    <th>Status</th>
                    <th>Description</th>
                    <th>Created At</th>
                    <th>Updated At</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                @if($products)
                    @foreach($products as $product)
                        <tr>
                            <td>{{$product->id}}</td>
                            <td><img src="" alt="">{{$product->photo ? $product->photo->file : 'no item photo'}}</td>
                            <td>{{$product->cname}}</td>
                            <td>{{$product->title}}</td>
                            <td>{{$product->price}}</td>
                            <td>{{$product->status == 1 ? "Active" : "Not Active"}}</td>
                            <td>{{$product->description}}</td>
                            <td>{{$product->created_at->diffForHumans()}}</td>
                            <td>{{$product->updated_at->diffForHumans()}}</td>
                        </tr>
                    @endforeach
                @endif
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
<!-- /#page-wrapper -->



@include('includes.footer')
```

Comment: share your controller code

Comment: Can you show the code from your controller, i'm guessing your products are not correct, perhaps the query or you didn't pass the variable correctly

Comment: it seems to be, it's something really obvious but couldn't find it.

Comment: Have you turned on `error_reporting` and `display_errors`? What's inside your view file? Have you altered anything inside `Product`? Is the route correct?

Comment: route is correct and data is perfectly stored in the database so there's no issues regarding that.

Comment: Can you show your blade code?

Comment: Is there anything in `includes.header` that might cause the error exception?

Comment: I would go to the storage/logs folder for today and see if Laravel is writing any errors to it.

Comment: You can test your fetched data first in your index method using dd() and make sure you get the products

Comment: you should create a layout file and add yield('section name') and in product.index just extend that layout and drop your data inside the section you defined... right now you are not using any layout file

Comment: there's nothing in the includes.header which should cause the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main issue is it is behaving like the route is not defined and its view are not set (which is really not the case). I have defined it like

```
Route::resource('/admin/product','ProductController');
```

and it is returning me[image: routes]
how could that be possible if the routes are defined and it's not returning it's view.

> I have created a custom route and view for it, and returned it's(index.blade.php) view to it and now it's working.